# How to structure controllers that communicate with databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm pretty new to the concept of patterns. I am practising my dependency injection skills as well as using DAO principles. The code I have written works but I feel that it can be written in a more elegant fashion. I've tried restructuring it a pattern I saw but that complicated things so not sure if I implemented it correctly. As a general rule when a web application communicates with a database and throws out result, how should one structure their project?
 I've heard of the MVC principle but that doesn't necessarily add database to the mix.

This is what I have so far:

A class containing a controller in a `Controller` package:

```
@RestController
public class ResponseController {

    @Autowired
    MongoBase dbConnection;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/jsonresult", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String jsonresult(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id){

        return dbConnection.documentToJSON(id, Constants.database,Constants.collection);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/alljsonresult", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String alljsonresult(){

        return dbConnection.allDocumentToJSON(Constants.database,Constants.collection);
    }}
```

A class containing CRUD methods to the database in a `Database` package:

```
@Component
public class MongoBase {

    @Autowired
    MongoClient mongoClient;

    public MongoBase() {
        try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printAllCollection(String databaseName, String collectionName) {

        ...

    }
```

So is there a better way/more efficient way of writing thi? Also I feel I haven't fully implemented DI in the `Monogbase` class since it contains the `new` keyword..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using springboot, then you don't need this old style
also don't need to create mongoClient bean your self, spring boot help you in it
You just need to add following properties in **application.properties** file

```
#mongodb 
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost 
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017  
spring.data.mongodb.database=app1
```

Also declares a spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb in your pom or gradle 
it's a cool and super awesome dependency for accessing Data with MongoDB
you can read about it from here[https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/]

suppose you have a domain
@Document(collection = "domain")

```
public class User {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String domain;

    private boolean displayAds;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Now if we need to perform curd operation on this domain, extends MongoRepository, you have CRUD function automatically. Spring data come with many magic findBy queries, review the official Spring data MongoDB – Query methods for detail.

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {

    Domain findFirstByDomain(String domain);

    Domain findByDomainAndDisplayAds(String domain, boolean displayAds);

    //Supports native JSON query string
    @Query("{domain:'?0'}")
    Domain findCustomByDomain(String domain);

    @Query("{domain: { $regex: ?0 } })")
    List<Domain> findCustomByRegExDomain(String domain);

}
```

UserRepository extends the MongoRepository interface and plugs in the type of values and id it works with: User and Long. Out-of-the-box, this interface comes with many operations, including standard CRUD operations (create-read-update-delete).

now you can easly use it in your controller
@RestController

```
public class ResponseController {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    User create(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
        return userRepository.create(user);
    }

}
```

also you can do with it lot of things. you just need to go throw with it doc.

Also you you can use mongoTemplate for execute the query

```
 @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Comment: The Spring Data recommendation is excellent.  Spring Boot is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend some improvements to your solution:

1. You're using Spring.  You should not create any injected beans using `new`.  Let Spring instantiate and manage those beans for you.
2. Use the `@Repository` annotation to mark your persistence class.
3. Make your repository class interface based.
4. Don't embed "Mongo" into the class name.  You happen to be using Mongo as your persistence provider now, but you may change your mind later.  Don't reveal implementation information in your class names - hide it.
5. The Controller is part of the UI.  It uses repositories and/or services to fulfill use cases.  It's perfectly correct to use Spring to inject the repository into the Controller.

I'd recommend that you use [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), an opinionated version of Spring.  Have a look at their [guides](https://spring.io/guides) to learn how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

When I build web applications I typically define the full chain as follows:

***Client Side:***

**View** - This is the **V** in MVC where you control visuals & user action derived workflow.

**Controller** - This is the **C** in MVC where workflow is managed. Most Client processing will go here and multiple Client calls can be made to get/send data or perform lookups.

**Client** - This is where you make a call to a REST web service and parse/deserialize the results/handle exceptions.

***Server Side:***

**RestController** (Sometimes Called Resource) - This is your REST API endpoint. Here you extract & validate a request.

**Service** - This is where most of your server logic will go. Sometimes you might have to make multiple data access calls or call other service functions.

**DataAccessObject** (Sometimes Called Provider) - This is your database interaction to pull data from your database into a model. CRUD operations (Create Read Update Delete)

**Example Scenario:**
Lets say we want to submit data & permissions for a given user

- UserView.jsp - User types in user & permission data and hits submit.
- UserController.java - validates User & permission data, does any necessary lookups, then calls UserClient.
- UserClient.java - Builds the REST request and calls the /user/create REST endpoint.
- UserRestController.java - Unpackages/Validates the request, then calls UserManagementService
- UserManagementService.java - Server Logic happens here! Lets say I have two tables in my database. A User table and a Permissions table. I want to store the user information in the User table and the permission information in the permission table so I will call the UserDAO for the user data and the PermissionDAO for the permission data.
- UserDAO & PermissionDAO - Saves The passed models to their respective tables.
- Return to Service, Return to RestController, Return to Client (Parse Response), Return to Controller (Move the Workflow forward with a redirect or a success message).

**Conclusion:**

This may seem like a lot of in-between steps but this design provides a ton of flexibility, especially if your building large, complex web services. Each component has a specific purpose, follows an easy naming convention, and splits complex logic into smaller, simpler steps.